# What is the ideal approach to optimising a large procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

My company has a procedure that takes a long time to run, in one of our applications.

This procedure is enormous and calls many different sub-procedures and functions.

Typically it has been worked on by many different people, for a lot of years and no one has looked to optimise it.

My question is - What would be the best way to approach optimising this procedure - is there a best practice guide to approaching something like this?

The task is so daunting I have no idea where to start. How would an expert start/tackle this?

I already know basic SQL Server optimisation e.g. execution plans / indexing / poorly written queries

Comment: If stored procedures are called (not functions) there is ability to print some messages. You can print number of rows, time for executing etc... It's little step instead of real debuging, but asserting usefull informations can be very usefull.

Comment: Noted: - excellent suggestion - now I just need a basic sequential list of executed procedures

Comment: It is possible to debug stored procedures in management studio

Comment: @Magnus: Yes, it can be steped step by step. You can see scalar values in parameters and variables. But the important data (the table variable, temporary tables, etc...) are not available. So the debuging of stored procedures is almost useless. All debuging I use are the asserts because the asserted data are more usefull.

Comment: @TcKs if the SP call lots of other SP's than stepping through it might fairly fast determine which sub SP there might be an performance problem with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your stored procedure calls sub-procedures and functions, I'd think of it as a tree (the procedure itself being the root), start from the leaves and, one function at a time, progress to the root.

This way, you can focus on a single task performed at a time, *and* have less code to check in any given moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you like the way of asserting values, I'l elaborate one of my practice for asserting in nested stored procedures.

**Disclaimer:** This aproach is not the best way for best performance in production systems. I recommend you comment all debuging asserts and select in production system. Especially the debug selects can totally broke the functionality when the nested are procedured returning table results to parent procedure!

Example first:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[MyTopLevelProc]
    @SomeText nvarchar(50),
    @SomeNumber bigint

    /* >>> parameters only for debug >>> */
    /* debug parameters should have always default values and should be last parameters of procedure. it is goog practice because of usage during development/production phase */
    , @EnableDebugSelects bit = NULL -- if 1, then table-results will be used for asserting table data for debuging
    , @LogIndent int = NULL -- determines indentation of text asserts
    /* <<< parameters only for debug <<< */
BEGIN
    IF @EnableDebugSelects IS NULL SET @EnableDebugSelects = 0
    IF @LogIndent IS NULL OR @LogIndent < 0 SET @LogIndent = 0

    /* @SubLogIndent = indentation for nested procedures */
    DECLARE @SubLogIndent int = @LogIndent + 1

    DECLARE @_CurrentProcName_ nvarchar(255) = '[dbo].[MyTopLevelProc]'
    EXEC x.LogStr @LogIndent, 'PROC: ', @_CurrentProcName_, ' >>>' -- asserts start of procedure

    EXEC x.LogStr @LogIndent, 'INSERT INTO _some_table_'
    INSERT INTO _some_table_ ( ... columns ... )
        SELECT ... columns ... FROM _other_table_
    EXEC x.LogRowCount @LogIndent, @@ROWCOUNT

    EXEC x.LogStr @LogIndent, 'Getting product names ...'
    DECLARE @TblProductName TABLE (
        ProductID int,
        ProductName nvarchar(50)
    )
    INSERT INTO @TblProductName (ProductID, ProductName)
        SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM _some_product_table_
    EXEC x.LogRowcount @LogIndent, @@ROWCOUNT

    IF @EnableDebugSelects = 1 BEGIN
        -- using the name of table-variable (@TblProductName) as column name is good practise for cases when the table variable has no rows. even from column names you can see which table-variable was selected
        SELECT '' AS [@TblProductName], * FROM @TblProductName
    END

    EXEC x.LogStr @LogIndent, 'Calling nested procedure ...'
    DECLARE @Result int
    EXEC @Result = [dbo].[AnotherProcedure]
                     @SomeTextParameter = 'Hello world!',
                     @SomeNumberParameter = 42,
                     /* we want pass debug parameters into nested procedures */
                     @EnableDebugSelects = @EnableDebugSelects,
                     @LogIndent = @SubLogIndent -- passing increased indentation for text asserts
    EXEC x.LogInt @LogIndent, '@Result: ', @Result

    EXEC x.LogStr @LogIndent, 'PROC: <<< ', @_CurrentProcName_ -- asserts end of procedure
END
```

The procedures `x.Log*` is my custom stored procedure in custom schema `x`. The body of stored procedures look like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [x].[Log]
    @LogIndent int = 0,
    @Str nvarchar(max),
    @Str2 nvarchar(max) = NULL,
    @Str3 nvarchar(max) = NULL,
    @Str4 nvarchar(max) = NULL,
    @Str5 nvarchar(max) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Msg nvarchar(max) = ''

IF @LogIndent IS NULL SET @LogIndent = 0
IF @LogIndent > 0 BEGIN
    DECLARE @i int = 0
    WHILE @i < @LogIndent BEGIN
        SET @i = @i + 1
        SET @Msg = @Msg + '    '
    END
END

IF NOT @Str IS NULL SET @Msg = @Msg + @Str
IF NOT @Str2 IS NULL SET @Msg = @Msg + @Str2
IF NOT @Str3 IS NULL SET @Msg = @Msg + @Str3
IF NOT @Str4 IS NULL SET @Msg = @Msg + @Str4
IF NOT @Str5 IS NULL SET @Msg = @Msg + @Str5

PRINT @Msg
END
```

The other `x.Log*` procedures are helper procedures like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LogInt]
    @LogIndent int = 0,
    @Num int,
    @Prefix nvarchar(max) = NULL,
    @Suffix nvarchar(max) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result int = 0

    DECLARE @Msg nvarchar(max) = ISNULL(CAST(@Num as nvarchar(max)), 'NULL')

    EXEC @Result = Log @LogIndent = @LogIndent
                , @Str = @Prefix
                , @Str2 = @Msg

    RETURN @Result
END
```

I hope, this will help you.